# Enable to set first time password for new developers account

Tags: developer

I signed up on https://developer.salesforce.com/. Got a Salesforce.com login confirmation mail with a link to set a password and password question and answer.

But clinking on the link gives error:
Your login attempt has failed. The username or password may be incorrect, or your location or login time may be restricted. Please contact the administrator at your company for help.

Using the forgot login option: First time it asked to give mother maiden name which i have not set. Second attempt onwards forgot login says You can not reset your password.

Any help to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

That's a bit hard to analyse from a community perspective - were you by any chance logged into any other salesforce org ? Sometimes when you have different sessions going on, it may try to redirect you or use your existing session.

If you can't figure it out, don't feel bad about just signup up for a new dev org with a different username, you can use the same email. That's perfectly fine and salesforce has no objections against that. Many developers have multiple dev orgs for R&D or prototyping.

**update (sfdcfox):**

You can also email support@salesforce.com and request a password reset. You should use the email address you signed up with to request the reset, and specify the username for the account.

Comment: You can also email support@salesforce.com and request a password reset. You should use the email address you signed up with to request the reset, and specify the username for the account.

Comment: Let me know the username which you have used to create the dev account and I will be able to help you. Thanks!