# Developer Edition Login: Activation Link Error

Tags: login-errors

I have created Developer Edition login in Force.com. I received the activation link in mail with subject line ***Salesforce.com login confirmation***, but upon clicking the activation link I am getting below error message –

> Your login attempt has failed. The username or password may be incorrect, or your location or login time may be restricted. Please
>   contact the administrator at your company for help.

Using the forgot login option: It asked to give mother maiden name which i have not set/configured.

Please help me in getting logged in to my login OR in resetting the password.

Comment: duplicate: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38446/enable-to-set-first-time-password-for-new-developers-account/38448#38448

Answer (score 1):

You can either create new account (they're free), or you can try contacting support to reset your password (email support@salesforce.com and give them your developer username).